# Is there any way to edit pipes while a process is running?

Tags: command-line

I sometimes work with processes that:

- Are slow to start up
- Run for a while
- Log a lot of information to standard out

For instance, imagine that this is a large web application.

Now suppose that, for a moment, I want to just see output lines that contain `foo`. I end up doing this:

```
$ heavy_process
# watch for a bit
# ah, now I just want to see lines that contain 'foo'
# (kill heavy_process)

$ heavy_process | grep foo
# watch for a bit
# ok, I'm statisfied about foo. Let's look at bar instead
# (kill heavy_process)

$ heavy_process | grep bar
```

It's frustrating to have to keep restarting `heavy_process` when I really just want to change the `| grep`.

**Is there a way to "add and remove pipes" from a pipeline in the command line?**

Comment: I suppose I could do `heavy_process > some_file 2>&1`, then separately, `tail -f some_file | grep foo`. Not sure how well that will do at preserving color, though.

Comment: this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process

Answer (score 1):

I suppose some **controlling process** cannot be avoided. I can think of different approaches. Either a dynamic pattern matcher (instead of `grep`), along the core of `awk '$0 ~ pat'`, where `pat` will dynamically be loaded (e.g. though a GNU `awk` co-process). Or a some primitive pattern injection solution, where the *change-pattern* directives are inserted in the data stream so that the `awk` filter can easily adjust the pattern on the fly, along the lines of:

```
mkfifo cmdfifo       # create once an asynchroneous communication channel

{ while read cmd < cmdfifo ; do printf "%s\n" "@$cmd" ; done &
  heavy_process ;} |
    awk '
        /^@/ { pat = substr($0,2) ; next }   # parse the injected pattern
        pat !="" && $0 ~ pat     # if pattern is set print matching lines
    '
```

To activate or switch search for a specific pattern you'd then use, e.g.,

```
echo bar > cmdfifo
```

to activate a match for "bar", and a subsequent

```
echo foo > cmdfifo
```

will dynamically change the pattern to "foo".

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your own suggestion is the best solution,
with the modification that you run the command in the background:

```
heavy_process > some_file &
```

Add `2>&1` if `heavy_process` writes text to stderr
that you want to be able to search for. 
Since you say that the programs "Log a lot of information to standard out",
I recommend not using `2>&1`. 
The `&` at the end of the command causes the process to run asynchronously,
which means that you can use your terminal for other things
while it’s running.  Depending on what shell you’re using,
you’ll probably be notified when it terminates.

To search through the output of the process *so far*, all you need is

```
grep foo some_file
```

To search through the output so far
*and continue to monitor the file as the process writes to it*, use

```
tail -n +1 -f some_file | grep foo
```

Without the `-n +1`, `tail` will give you only the last 10 lines of the file.

Answer (score -2):

You could write a script like as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash
while true;
do
        echo -n "Enter your regexp: "
        read myregexp
        heavy_process | grep "$myregexp"
done
```

You may interrupt the process at any moment with Ctrl-c

Comment: I think the point of the question was to keep `heavy_process` running and not restarting it (neither manually nor automatically) after every change of the pattern. (Your proposal **will** restart `heavy_process` after every pattern change.)

Comment: You're right I've missed that point, everytime that pass over loop run again. Perhaps script could be improved.

Comment: Perhaps script could be improved. Perhaps the answer should involve moving the heavy_process instead true, and finding a way to grep the output into the while loop.